# Select and display the value of a row in Shiny Datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I am totally new to R & Shiny, this would be my first project, which I was able to get to this point after going through some awesome tutorials.

I am trying a have the value of the selected row display in the textOutput. The code works with the selection, but I am not able to display the value of the selected row to the textOuput, as it shows [Object Object].

This is what I got so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
addr <- as.data.table(read.csv("addresses.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F))
names(addr) [1:4]<- c("STREET ADDRESS","CITY NAME","PROVINCE","POSTAL CODE")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, div(DT::dataTableOutput("addressTable"), style="font-family:verdana", align="left"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, div(textOutput("selectedAddress"), align="center"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$addressTable <- DT::renderDataTable({addr}, server = T, selection = 'single')

  output$selectedAddress <- DT::renderDataTable({
    selectedrowindex <<-input$addr_rows_selected
    selectedrowindex <<-as.numeric(selectedrowindex)
    selectedrow <- (addr[selectedrowindex,])
    selectedrow
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few adjustments:

1. Your syntax for accessing the selected rows was off slightly. From the `data.table` [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), the input is access with the ID passed to the `dataTableOutput()`; where you wrote `input$addr_rows_selected` you actually want `input$addressTable_rows_selected` in order to find the table rendered with `DT::dataTableOutput("addressTable")`.
2. You are mixing output types with render types. If you want the address to be output as text (per the line `textOutput("selectedAddress")`) then you should use `renderText()` rather than `DT::renderDataTable()`.
3. In order to render the address as text, you must take the address (components) and collapse it down to a character string, which can be done with `paste(...,collapse = ",")`

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
addr <- as.data.table(read.csv("addresses.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F))
names(addr) [1:4]<- c("STREET ADDRESS","CITY NAME","PROVINCE","POSTAL CODE")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, div(DT::dataTableOutput("addressTable"), style="font-family:verdana", align="left"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, div(textOutput("selectedAddress"), align="center"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$addressTable <- DT::renderDataTable({addr}, server = T, selection = 'single')

  output$selectedAddress <- renderText({
    selectedrowindex <- input$addressTable_rows_selected
    selectedrowindex <- as.numeric(selectedrowindex)
    selectedrow <- paste(addr[selectedrowindex,],collapse = ", ")
    selectedrow
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks @Wil. Just wondering what the collapse option at the end do?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks again.For anyone who is wondering what that option is for, it was for splitting the address components by ",".

Comment: I wouldn't word it as "splitting the...components". It combines elements of a vector into a single object. You can read `?paste` for more info, but `paste("a","b","c",collapse = ";")` would results in a character **scalar** `"a;b;c"`.